# I'm trying to understand this recursion code and have become stuck

Tags: javascript, recursion

I think I'm getting a grasp on recursion in Javascript but would appreciate some clarity on a specific recursion code I'm reviewing in a book I'm reading

The code below as I understand is proceeding through a few steps, which I'll explain if you can correct any errors in my understanding I would really appreciate it:

- The findSolution function is looking for a solution where you either
  add 5 or multiply by 3 to get to 24
- The function find is where the recursion happens to find this
  solution, the statement `if (start == target)`is what tells the
  recursion to end when it finds the solution and return the history of
  how this happens
- The return statement in lines 8-9 starts with (1 + 5) which equals 6,
  so it then starts back at the top proceeding through the if
  statements which isn't met then proceeds to the return statement
  again this time with (6 + 5) which equals 11
- It proceeds through this until one of the if statements is met. When
  start is higher than the target the function then proceeds to the the
  other side of the || statement and starts with (1 * 3) with the
  history being equivalent to "(1 * 3)"

What I'm unsure of is why does the function proceed through first part adding 5 to the (1 * 3) on the next iteration, how does the function know to add 5 and then on the next iteration multiply by 3? Why does it not continue to add 5 and then do so until it is too big and return null?

```
function findSolution(target) {
  function find(start, history) {
    if (start == target)
      return history;
    else if (start > target)
      return null;
    else
      return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
             find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
  }
  return find(1, "1");
}

console.log(findSolution(24));
// → (((1 * 3) + 5) * 3)
```

Comment: stuck in a loop? :p Can you please use paragraphs, that wall of text is not conducive to easy reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this makes it more clear what happens.

I've just added a `depth`-argument to the `find`-function to determine the recursive-depth, and a `console.log()` to log all recursive calls.

```js
function findSolution(target) {
    //added a depth-property to show the recursion better
    function find(start, history, depth) {
        //simply log all calls in order
        console.log("%s%d == %s", "|  ".repeat(depth), start, history);

        if (start == target)
            return history;
        else if (start > target)
            return null;
        else
            return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)", depth+1) ||
                   find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)", depth+1);
    }
    return find(1, "1", 0);
}

console.log(findSolution(24));
```

Answer (score 1):

It actually did go through every possible cases that you mentioned. It did continue to add 5 until it was too big and return null (in this case `find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") === null (false)` so the result will come from the other branch.

It's really hard to explain cause you need to understand execution stack or maybe draw a tree of execution.
Let me know how can I help

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of your code that will print an execution tree for you so that you can follow along with all the different permutations that the algorithm is, in fact, trying:

```
function findSolution(target) {
  function find(start, history, trace) {
    trace.push(history)
    if (start == target) {
      console.log(trace.join(' => ') + ' => ' + start + ' == ' + target);
      return history;
    }
    if (start > target) {
      console.log(trace.join(' => ') + ' => ' + start + ' > ' + target);
      return null;
    }
    return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)", [].slice.call(trace)) ||
           find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)", [].slice.call(trace));
  }
  return find(1, "1", []);
}
findSolution(24)
```

Here is the execution tree:

```
1 => (1 + 5) => ((1 + 5) + 5) => (((1 + 5) + 5) + 5) => ((((1 + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) => (((((1 + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) => 26 > 24
1 => (1 + 5) => ((1 + 5) + 5) => (((1 + 5) + 5) + 5) => ((((1 + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) => (((((1 + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) * 3) => 63 > 24
1 => (1 + 5) => ((1 + 5) + 5) => (((1 + 5) + 5) + 5) => ((((1 + 5) + 5) + 5) * 3) => 48 > 24
1 => (1 + 5) => ((1 + 5) + 5) => (((1 + 5) + 5) * 3) => 33 > 24
1 => (1 + 5) => ((1 + 5) * 3) => (((1 + 5) * 3) + 5) => ((((1 + 5) * 3) + 5) + 5) => 28 > 24
1 => (1 + 5) => ((1 + 5) * 3) => (((1 + 5) * 3) + 5) => ((((1 + 5) * 3) + 5) * 3) => 69 > 24
1 => (1 + 5) => ((1 + 5) * 3) => (((1 + 5) * 3) * 3) => 54 > 24
1 => (1 * 3) => ((1 * 3) + 5) => (((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) => ((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) + 5) => (((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) => ((((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) => 28 > 24
1 => (1 * 3) => ((1 * 3) + 5) => (((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) => ((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) + 5) => (((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) => ((((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) + 5) + 5) * 3) => 69 > 24
1 => (1 * 3) => ((1 * 3) + 5) => (((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) => ((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) + 5) => (((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) + 5) * 3) => 54 > 24
1 => (1 * 3) => ((1 * 3) + 5) => (((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) => ((((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) * 3) => 39 > 24
1 => (1 * 3) => ((1 * 3) + 5) => (((1 * 3) + 5) * 3) => 24 == 24
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the function `find` starts with 1. Inside find:

- if what we have is equal to the result we return the history that got us here
- if not, we see if we have passed the target (what we have is already greater than the target so multiplying by `3`s or adding `5`s won't get us to it).
- lastly, if we are bellow the target. Then we take what we have so far (the history, both literal (the string) an numerical (the result)) start two branches one by adding a `5` and the other by multiplying by `3`.

The first call to find was with the result of `1` and the history of `"1"`.

Inside that first `find` the test (`start == target`) will fail since (1 != 24), the second test (`start > target`) will fail too because (1 <= 24). So we executes what inside the `else`. So we call find which will take a result of (`1 + 5`) and a history of (`"( 1 + 5)"`) and we check if we've got a history that got us to `24` (the returned value won't be `null`) or if the returned value is `null` then call another find with the result of (`1 * 3)`) and the history of (`"( 1 * 3 "`) and we check if we got a returned value different from `null` (the right answer) or not (there is no answer).

It will be best if it was represented by a tree view with all the possible calls:

```
[1] -> [1 + 5] -> [6 + 5] -> [11 + 5] -> [16 + 5] -> [21 + 5] >> branch terminated (26 > 24)
   |          |          |           |            -> [21 * 3] >> branch terminated (63 > 24)
   |          |          |            -> [16 * 3] >> branch terminated (48 > 24)
   |          |           -> [11 * 3] >> branch terminated (33 > 24)
   |           -> [6 * 3] >> returns the right result (24 == 24)
   |
   |
   | We will never have the next branch because we already got a result.
    -> [1 * 3] -> [3 + 5] -> [8 + 5] -> [13 + 5] -> [18 + 5] -> [23 + 5] >> branch would have been terminated (28 > 24)
              |          |          |           |            -> [23 * 3] >> branch would have been terminated (69 > 24)
              |          |          |            -> [18 * 3] >> branch would have been terminated (54 > 24)
              |          |           -> [13 * 3] >> branch would have been terminated (39 > 24)
              |           -> [8 * 3] >> would have been a correct answer if we haven't already got one
               -> [3 * 3] -> [9 + 5] -> [14 + 5] -> [19 + 5] >> would have been a correct answer if we haven't already got one
                         |          |            -> [19 * 3] >> terminated ...
                         |           -> [14 * 3] >> terminated ...
                          -> [9 * 3] >> terminated ...
```

The terminated branches means that the condition (`start > target`) was met so a returned `null` to the caller which will have 3 possible outcomes:

1. If the caller is another `find` and the `find` that returned `null` is the first `find` in `find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") || find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)")` then we call find with a `* 3` branch.
2. If the caller is another `find` and the `find` that returned `null` is the second `find` in `find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") || find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)")` then we return a `null` which will terminates the parent barnch (this `find`).
3. If the caller is `findSolution` then the target was never acheived using just `+ 5` and `* 3` combo.

The `find` that returned a correct answer (in other words the `find` that met the condition `start == target`) will prevent more branches to be created (it will return a non `null` result which will be returned by its caller and its caller before it ... all the way to `findSolution`) so if we are at the first `find` in `find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") || find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)")` the second one will never be executed.